# AWS apigateway removes the proxy on the second implementation of the template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, aws-codepipeline

I have the following cloudformation template that is responsible for creating the apigateway, lambda functions and is also creating a resource called /{proxy+} within the apigateway, which is the one that is mainly in charge if the user when I go through the authorizer is correct, then I do it redirects to my application that is inside an ec2, I designed this infrastructure to be able to divide my application into lambda functions that have an apigateway since that part of my application is reading and my other part of the application is in an ec2 that is writing, the problem I have is that when I make the request from postman I get the following error, the problem I currently have is that when I deploy with codepipeline, the first deployment my apigateway creates the proxy but when for example I comment some apis or create some apis inside any lambda function my proxy in the apigateway is removed so it doesn't appear in the new implementations. I don't understand why this is happening, I already tried to divide the master template into small ones and this did not solve it, I also tried to deploy it with codepipeline since before I deployed it with github actions with sam and now in code pipeline I deploy it with aws cloudformation, but this does not solve I don't understand why I made this error, has anyone experienced something like this? Because there is not much information about this type of error.
I currently had a security group that had my vpc so my lambdas could access my database through a proxy.

AWS apigateway removes the proxy on the second implementation of the template.

This is my template

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Stack testing

Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: Environment in which the resources will be deploy
    Type: String
    Default: development
  EnvironmentNewVersion:
    Description: Environment New version
    Type: String
    Default: develop
  SQSBatchSize:
    Description: sqs batch size
    Type: String
    Default: 5
  AuthorizerTimeout:
    Description: authorizer timeout
    Type: String
    Default: 60
  DBSuffix:
    Description: dynamodb table suffix
    Type: String
    Default: subfix_db
  TokenExpiration:
    Description: token expiration
    Type: String
    Default: 120
  GlobalTimeout:
    Description: global timeout
    Type: String
    Default: 60
  DyanmoDBReadCapacityUnits:
    Description: dynamodb read capacity units
    Type: String
    Default: 5
  DyanmoDBWriteCapacityUnits:
    Description: dynamodb write capacity units
    Type: String
    Default: 5
  VpcId:
    Description: VPC ID
    Type: String
    Default: vpc-1
  SubnetA:
    Description: Subnet A
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-1
  SubnetB:
    Description: Subnet B
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-2
  UrlElasticBeanstalk:
    Description: Url Elastic Beanstalk
    Type: String
    Default: test.com
  SecretKey:
    Description: Secret Key
    Type: String
    Default: secret_key
  EnvAwsAccessKey:
    Description: Env aws access key
    Type: String
    Default: access key
  EnvAwsSecretAccessKey:
    Description: Env Aws Secret access key
    Type: String
    Default: secret_access_key
  EnvAwsRegion:
    Description: Secret Key
    Type: String
    Default: env_aws_region
  DBUser:
    Description: database user
    Type: String
    Default: testing-database-user
  DBPassword:
    Description: database password
    Type: String
    Default: testing-database-password
  DBHostWriter:
    Description: database host writer
    Type: String
    Default: testing-database-host-writer
  DBHostRead:
    Description: database host read
    Type: String
    Default: testing-database-host-read
  DBPort:
    Description: database port
    Type: String
    Default: testing-database-port
  DBName:
    Description: database name
    Type: String
    Default: testing-database-name
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: !Ref GlobalTimeout
    Tracing: Active
    MemorySize: 256
    Handler: app.handler
    Runtime: python3.9
    Architectures:
      - x86_64
    VpcConfig:
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref LambdasSecurityGroup
      SubnetIds:
        - !Ref SubnetA
        - !Ref SubnetB
    Environment:
      Variables:
        ENVIRONMENT: !Ref Environment
        SECRET_KEY: !Ref SecretKey
        ENV_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: !Ref EnvAwsAccessKey
        ENV_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: !Ref EnvAwsSecretAccessKey
        ENV_AWS_REGION: !Ref EnvAwsRegion
        DB_USER: !Ref DBUser
        DB_PASSWORD: !Ref DBPassword
        DB_HOST_WRITER: !Ref DBHostWriter
        DB_HOST_READ: !Ref DBHostRead
        DB_PORT: !Ref DBPort
        DB_NAME: !Ref DBName
Resources:
  LambdasSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow lambda to access proxy database
      VpcId: !Ref VpcId
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
        - IpProtocol: -1
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Sub lambdas-security-group-${AWS::StackName}-${Environment}

  Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Name: !Sub api-${AWS::StackName}-${Environment}
    Properties:
      TracingEnabled: true
      StageName: !Ref Environment
      Cors:
        AllowOrigin: "'*'"
        AllowMethods: "'*'"
        AllowHeaders: "'*'"
      Auth:
        DefaultAuthorizer: LambdaAuthorizer
        AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: false
        Authorizers:
          LambdaAuthorizer:
            FunctionArn: !GetAtt AuthorizerFunction.Arn

  # LayerDependencies:
  #   Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
  #   Properties:
  #     LayerName: !Sub layer-dependencies-${AWS::StackName}-${Environment}
  #     Description: Libraries python dependencies basic
  #     ContentUri: ./layer_dependencies_basic/layer_dependencies_basic.zip
  #     CompatibleRuntimes:
  #       - python3.9

  AuthorizersDBTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
      TableName: !Sub db_authorizer-${DBSuffix}-${Environment}
      AttributeDefinitions:
        - AttributeName: uuid
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        - AttributeName: uuid
          KeyType: HASH
      TimeToLiveSpecification:
        AttributeName: expires_at
        Enabled: true
      ProvisionedThroughput:
        ReadCapacityUnits: !Ref DyanmoDBReadCapacityUnits
        WriteCapacityUnits: !Ref DyanmoDBWriteCapacityUnits

  AuthFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: modules/auth
      FunctionName: !Sub auth-${AWS::StackName}-${Environment}
      Description: !Sub Auth microservice «${Environment}»
      # Layers:
      #   - !Ref LayerDependencies
      Environment:
        Variables:
          FUNCTION_NAME: !Sub token-${AWS::StackName}-${Environment}
          TOKEN_EXPIRATION: !Ref TokenExpiration
          AUTHORIZER_TABLE: !Sub db_authorizer-${DBSuffix}-${Environment}
      Policies:
        - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
      Events:
        validateAuth:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref Api
            Path: /auth
            Method: GET
        Singin:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref Api
            Path: /v3/testing/auth
            Method: POST
            Auth:
              Authorizer: NONE
        Singup:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref Api
            Path: /auth/signup
            Method: POST
            Auth:
              Authorizer: NONE
        Social:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref Api
            Path: /auth/social
            Method: POST
            Auth:
              Authorizer: NONE
        # SocialRegister:
        #   Type: Api
        #   Properties:
        #     RestApiId: !Ref Api
        #     Path: /auth/social/register
        #     Method: POST
        # GetUser:
        #   Type: Api
        #   Properties:
        #     RestApiId: !Ref Api
        #     Path: /auth/get_user
        #     Method: GET

  AuthorizerFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: modules/authorizer
      FunctionName: !Sub authorizer-${AWS::StackName}-${Environment}
      Description: !Sub Authorizer microservice «${Environment}»
      # Layers:
      #   - !Ref LayerDependencies
      VpcConfig: ~
      Environment:
        Variables:
          FUNCTION_NAME: !Sub authorizer-${AWS::StackName}-${Environment}
          AUTHORIZER_TABLE: !Sub db_authorizer-${DBSuffix}-${Environment}
      Policies:
        - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess

  ProxyResource:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Resource
    Properties:
      ParentId: !GetAtt Api.RootResourceId
      PathPart: "{proxy+}"
      RestApiId: !Ref Api

  ProxyMethod:
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Method
    Properties:
      AuthorizationType: NONE
      HttpMethod: ANY
      ResourceId: !Ref ProxyResource
      RestApiId: !Ref Api
      Integration:
        IntegrationHttpMethod: ANY
        Type: HTTP_PROXY
        Uri: "http://${stageVariables.VPCNLB}/{proxy}/"

  ProxyDeployment1:
    DependsOn:
      - ProxyMethod
    Type: AWS::ApiGateway::Deployment
    Properties:
      RestApiId: !Ref Api
      StageName: !Ref Environment
Outputs:
  Region:
    Description: "Region"
    Value: !Ref AWS::Region
  MyApi:
    Value: !Ref Api
  ApiUrl:
    Value: !Sub "https://${Api}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/${Environment}"
    Description: URL de la API
```

buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.1

phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - aws cloudformation package --template-file template_v2.yaml --s3-bucket codepipeline-deploy-test --output-template-file outPutTemplateSam.yaml
artifacts:
  type: zip
  files:
    - outPutTemplateSam.yaml
```

Try instead of deploying with github actions with sam, deploy with codepipeline, it did not work, also separate my template into smaller ones but the error continued.

Comment: You should translate the title into English, too!